# How to display editable PDFs as flat PDFs in browser?

Tags: php, pdf

I'm currently storing bunch of editable PDFs on the server which I'm trying to fetch using PHP and display using reader(), the issue is that while flat PDFs display just fine, the editable PDFs choke up the browser.

Currently the block of code looks like this;

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize (''.$PDFURL.'' ) ); 
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
header("Content-disposition: inline;     
filename=".basename(''.$PDFURL.''));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$filepath = readfile(''.$PDFURL.'');
```

What am I missing?

Edit: The reason for that approach is to find a way to display the PDF using native tools in Mozilla Firefox (Intranet with no outside access, Mozilla is de facto browser) and hide the PDF URL (sensitive information).

As stated before, both PDFs open fine if opened with Mozilla, flat PDF opens fine through HTML but the fillable PDF throws a fit when opened with HTML.

Comment: You are not actually displaying the document in any way. You're just submitting it to the browser and letting it handle as it sees fit. Whether to use an in-browser JavaScript renderer or an external PDF reader is up to the end user.

Comment: How do I tell the browser how to handle these editable PDFs?

Comment: There's no internet API to say "Open it with Adobe Reader DC", if that's what you mean. At most, you can implement your own JavaScript-based reader with the jsPDF library (just like you can implement your own JavaScript-based date picker) but of course that's precisely the reader you don't want.

Comment: Flat PDFs open fine with the inbuilt reader, but the editable PDFs are throwing a fit. The inbuilt reader is AR, but it is not handling the editability of the PDF graciously. I'm looking if there's a way to either flatten the PDF or refine the html params to force the browser to properly handle the file, so far no luck :(

Comment: The problem is likely with the PDF reader or the PDFs, not your code.

Comment: @DanWilson PDF reader opens fine if I open the files manually through my browser-of-choice, both flat and fillable form. The issue is that one type of pdf includes fillable boxes which I struggle to find a way to flatten